# How do I notify others on comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, tagging

How do I notify others on a comment? @is not loading names?

Tried many times.

Comment: Have you checked that your browser isn't having javascript issues? I know I've only ever had problems with the @ flag on comments when I've had javascript turned off.

Comment: @KatePaulknow it worked. I didnt do anything. let me try in my actual comment section.

Comment: @RK007: It may seem counter intuitive, but the @ tagging doesn't load any names if there would be only one name to show. In that case, the whole tagging system is suppressed (any manually typed tag is also removed).